# Python Dataframes - Breaking out single rows with duplicate columns into multiple rows and fewer columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

| A | B | C | Date1 | Time1 | Value1 | Date2 | Time2 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | def | ghi | 01-01-2000 | 15:00:00 | 100 | 01-01-2000 | 19:00:00 | 110 |

There are duplicate columns for Date/Time/Value and I would like to merge them into a single column. The
tricky part is that I would like the values of columns A/B/C to be shown for each new row added.
Something like this:

| A | B | C | Date | Time | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | def | ghi | 01-01-2000 | 15:00:00 | 100 |
| abc | def | ghi | 01-01-2000 | 19:00:00 | 110 |

The only approach I could think of was to take a subset of the original dataframe such as:

| A | B | C | Date1 | Time1 | Value1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | def | ghi | 01-01-2000 | 15:00:00 | 100 |

AND

| A | B | C | Date2 | Time2 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | def | ghi | 01-01-2000 | 19:00:00 | 110 |

Then try to merge them together. There has to be a faster way to do this. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: [pd.wide_to_long](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

Comment: Hi Quang, this does not work when rows are not unique. Unfortunately, the dataset I am working through are not unique. The Date/Time is what make the rows unique but I need to melt those as well. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

`pd.wide_to_long` works fine for this; however, if your indices are not unique, [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) can be helpful here, and is efficient:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.pivot_longer(
     index = ['A','B','C'], 
     names_to = '.value', 
     names_pattern = r"(\D+)\d")

     A    B    C        Date      Time  Value
0  abc  def  ghi  01-01-2000  15:00:00    100
1  abc  def  ghi  01-01-2000  19:00:00    110
```

The `.value` here determines which part of the columns remain as column headers; this is determined from the grouped regex in `named_pattern`.